# Removing Punctuation Marks except smiles - R, tm package

Tags: r, text-mining, tm, punctuation

I am using tm package, in R. I want to remove all punctuation marks from this text, except the smiles.

```
data <- c("conflict need resolved :<. turned conversation exchange ideas richer environment one tricky concepts :D , �conflict� always top business agendas :>. maybe different ideas/opinions different :) " )
```

I have tried

`library(tm)
 data <- gsub("[^a-z]", " ", data, ignore.case = TRUE)`

that is removing all punctuation, include smiles, as output

```
data <- conflict need resolved turned conversation exchange ideas richer environment one tricky concepts conflict always top business agendas maybe different ideas opinions different
```

when I need,

```
data <- conflict need resolved :< turned conversation exchange ideas richer environment one tricky concepts :D conflict always top business agendas :> maybe different ideas opinions different :)
```

Suggestion pls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write a dictionary of smiley, replace them all with text, remove the punctuation, and then replace them back.

```
# Make the dictionary. You need to make sure the strings are not in the text, which can be tested with something like stri_match(str=data,regex = smiles$r)
smiles <- data.frame(s=c(":<",":>",":)",":(",";)",":D"),
                     r=c("unhappyBracket","happyBracket","happyParen","unhappyParen","winkSmiley","DSmiley"))

library(stringi)
## replace smiley with text
data <- stri_replace_all_fixed(data,pattern = smiles$s,replacement = smiles$r,vectorize_all = FALSE)
## remove punctuation
data <- gsub("[^a-z]", " ", data, ignore.case = TRUE)
## replace text-smiley with punctuation smiley
data <- stri_replace_all_fixed(data,pattern = smiles$r,replacement = smiles$s,vectorize_all = FALSE)
```

Note that if the smiley are important to your analysis, you should leave them as words, since they will be easier to manipulate this way. Also, you may want to look into `tm::removePunctuation()` and `tm::tm_map` to handle the punctuation removal step.

Comment: Thank you very much @scoa for your great suggestion. An idea came in my mind from your comment, as I want to classify sentences based on smiles, and that's why if I remove all the English words,and keep only smiles symbol, don't you think it will be better? :)

Comment: I think only you can answer that, as this depends on your research question. All I am saying is that smileys should be coded as words in order to analyze them